# Windows XP - Security Update for Windows XP (KB923561) (KB946648) (KB956572) (KB958644)

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update

My father's computer has Windows XP, but when I try to install the service packs it always fails.  What gives?

Here are the errors that I get in the event log:

---

Date: 2/6/2010
Time: 12:02:18 AM
Type: Error
User: N/A
Computer: EVO
Source: Windows Update Agent
Category: Installation
Event ID: 20

Installation Failure: Windows failed to install the following update with error 0x80070002: Security Update for Windows XP (KB946648).

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

```
0000: 57 69 6e 33 32 48 52 65   Win32HRe
0008: 73 75 6c 74 3d 30 78 38   sult=0x8
0010: 30 30 37 30 30 30 32 20   0070002 
0018: 55 70 64 61 74 65 49 44   UpdateID
0020: 3d 7b 38 33 44 31 41 44   ={83D1AD
0028: 46 35 2d 37 37 39 44 2d   F5-779D-
0030: 34 30 31 36 2d 38 43 33   4016-8C3
0038: 31 2d 35 34 39 32 37 30   1-549270
0040: 46 36 37 42 33 46 7d 20   F67B3F} 
0048: 52 65 76 69 73 69 6f 6e   Revision
0050: 4e 75 6d 62 65 72 3d 31   Number=1
0058: 30 34 20 00               04 .
```

---

Date: 2/6/2010
Time: 12:02:18 AM
Type: Error
User: N/A
Computer: EVO
Source: Windows Update Agent
Catagory: Installation
Event ID: 20

Installation Failure: Windows failed to install the following update with error 0x80070002: Security Update for Windows XP (KB956572).

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

```
0000: 57 69 6e 33 32 48 52 65   Win32HRe
0008: 73 75 6c 74 3d 30 78 38   sult=0x8
0010: 30 30 37 30 30 30 32 20   0070002 
0018: 55 70 64 61 74 65 49 44   UpdateID
0020: 3d 7b 44 46 32 46 30 41   ={DF2F0A
0028: 39 38 2d 36 45 33 35 2d   98-6E35-
0030: 34 33 37 39 2d 41 42 33   4379-AB3
0038: 33 2d 41 30 33 30 33 45   3-A0303E
0040: 46 37 34 42 32 41 7d 20   F74B2A} 
0048: 52 65 76 69 73 69 6f 6e   Revision
0050: 4e 75 6d 62 65 72 3d 31   Number=1
0058: 30 32 20 00               02 .
```

---

Date: 2/6/2010
Time: 12:02:18 AM
Type: Error
User: N/A
Computer EVO
Source: Windows Update Agent
Event ID: 20

Installation Failure: Windows failed to install the following update with error 0x80070002: Security Update for Windows XP (KB958644).

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

```
0000: 57 69 6e 33 32 48 52 65   Win32HRe
0008: 73 75 6c 74 3d 30 78 38   sult=0x8
0010: 30 30 37 30 30 30 32 20   0070002 
0018: 55 70 64 61 74 65 49 44   UpdateID
0020: 3d 7b 39 33 39 37 41 32   ={9397A2
0028: 31 46 2d 32 34 36 43 2d   1F-246C-
0030: 34 35 33 42 2d 41 43 30   453B-AC0
0038: 35 2d 36 35 42 46 34 46   5-65BF4F
0040: 43 36 42 36 38 42 7d 20   C6B68B} 
0048: 52 65 76 69 73 69 6f 6e   Revision
0050: 4e 75 6d 62 65 72 3d 31   Number=1
0058: 30 31 20 00               01 .
```

---

Date: 2/6/2010
Time: 12:02:18 AM
Type: Error
User: N/A
Computer: EVO
Source: Windows Update Agent
Category: Installation
Event ID: 20

Installation Failure: Windows failed to install the following update with error 0x80070002: Security Update for Windows XP (KB923561).

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

```
0000: 57 69 6e 33 32 48 52 65   Win32HRe
0008: 73 75 6c 74 3d 30 78 38   sult=0x8
0010: 30 30 37 30 30 30 32 20   0070002 
0018: 55 70 64 61 74 65 49 44   UpdateID
0020: 3d 7b 33 31 30 41 34 43   ={310A4C
0028: 30 38 2d 35 39 33 44 2d   08-593D-
0030: 34 31 41 33 2d 42 42 35   41A3-BB5
0038: 37 2d 38 33 42 33 38 36   7-83B386
0040: 44 37 37 33 42 35 7d 20   D773B5} 
0048: 52 65 76 69 73 69 6f 6e   Revision
0050: 4e 75 6d 62 65 72 3d 31   Number=1
0058: 30 33 20 00               03 .
```

---

Thank you,
   Andrew

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the error is when it fails?

Comment: ...and how you're installing them.  via automatic updates, the windows update site, downloaded full installers?

Comment: "We need more input. We gotta fill this thing up with data. We gotta make her as real as possible, Wyatt. I want her to live. I want her to breathe. I want her to aerobicize."

Comment: @quack Automatic updates.

Comment: Okay added error messages...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution here

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910336

Stop the Automatic Updates service. To do this, follow these steps:

Click Start, click Run, type services.msc, and then click OK.
Right-click the Automatic Updates service, and then click Stop.
Minimize the Services snap-in.

Rename the SoftwareDistribution directory. To do this, follow these steps:

Click Start, click Run, type cmd, and then click OK.
Type cd %windir%, and then press ENTER.
Type ren SoftwareDistribution SDTemp, and then press ENTER
Type exit, and then press ENTER .

Note: When you remove the %windir%\softwaredistribution folder, the history list is erased from the "Review your Updates" section of the Windows Update Web site. This action will not affect the currently installed updates on your computer. Subsequent updates will appear in the history list.

Start the Automatic Updates service. To do this, follow these steps:

Maximize the Services snap-in.
Right-click the Automatic Updates service, and then click Start.
Close the Services snap-in window.
Visit the Windows Update Web site, the Microsoft Update Web site, or the WSUS server again, and then download an update.

If you still receive the same errors, verify that you have correctly performed steps 1 through 3.

If you still cannot install the update, see the following Microsoft Knowledge Base article:
[906602](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/906602/)  How to troubleshoot Windows Update, Microsoft Update, and Windows Server Update Services installation issues.

.

Comment: Okay I stopped the Automatic Updates service, and I renamed the SoftwareDistribution Directory.  I started the Automatic Updates Service back up again, and the SoftwareDistribution directory was recreated as the updates were downloaded.  The following updates were downloaded this time (KB946648, KB952004, KB956572, KB958644, KB959426) and after a reboot it appears to have worked.  Thanks! :)

Comment: It only took 7 months ;-> Glad you solved it.

Comment: Well it was on my Dad's machine, aren't too many evenings the thing is free....

Comment: I knew there was a logical answer, just didn't know what it could be. Curiosity killed the cat, but satisfaction brought it back to life!

Answer (score 0):

Was the original XP installation tweaked with [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/)? This can lead to some SP problems. But yes, more details needed.

Comment: Nope I don't recall doing that.